# UNICODE always defined in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

I use Visual Studio 2013 and I set my project's Character Set to **Use Multi-Byte Character Set** but still if I write

```
LPTSTR foo = new TCHAR[1000];
```

foo becomes a `wchar_t*`. On https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx it says that

```
#ifdef UNICODE
 typedef LPWSTR LPTSTR;
#else
 typedef LPSTR LPTSTR;
#endif
```

hence I would suspect that since I do not use UNICODE foo would be a `char*`

Have I misunderstood anything conceptual, or something in the studio?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you confirm that LPTSTR becomes `wchar_t*` when MBCS is selected as the character type?

Comment: In debugging mode, by checking the Type in the Locals view

Comment: Forget about the debugger.  When you call a function such as `OutputDebugString`, what is the string type that is expected?  If you're saying that you can't do this in an MBCS program: `OutputDebugString("abc123");` then your Visual Studio is broken.  If you choose a Unicode build, *then* such a line of code will give a compiler error.  No such error should occur for MBCS.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: I get a build error when building `OutputDebugString("abc123");` in my MBCS project:

`'void OutputDebugStringW(LPCWSTR)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [7]' to 'LPCWSTR'`

Comment: OutputDebugString(L"abc123"); works

Comment: There are two settings for MBCS vs. Unicode: One for the debug build and another for the release build. I suspect that you changed one but are now building the other.

Comment: Visual Studio is a proper IDE. Right click on `TCHAR` and choose "Go to definition". It's not magic, Visual Studio will show you the actual type behind `TCHAR`.

Comment: @DoubleTrouble If you get an error, then you are building a Unicode application.  If it were actually MBCS, then no error should have occurred.  Maybe you changed build configurations (Debug to Release maybe), and you didn't change your configuration to MBCS?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: I cannot believe how stupid I am.You were indeed correct that I changed the configuration for Release mode. I'm sorry for wasting your time :/